# Can an android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest be used with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, android-camera, android

I've worked on this for days now. I have an OpenCV/JavaCameraView-based project I am trying to integrate with an Android `android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest` object I use to control the camera's sensitivity to light.

The `CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2/JavaCameraView` project works (I can see an image on the screen), and the `CaptureRequest` project works (see this, too), but combining the two technologies in a single project has proved a big problem.

Has anyone gotten these two technologies to work together? My goal is to have the camera under the control of the CaptureRequest (limited SENSOR_SENSITIVITY + SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME), but for the screen to show a streaming image filtered through an OpenCV shared library I've written.

To control the camera, I can use something like this:

```
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, mImageReader.getSurface()),
                new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                        // The camera is already closed
                        if (null == mCameraDevice) {
                            return;
                        }
                        long exposureTime = 66259688,frameDuration = 1000;
                        int sensitivity = 1512;

                        mCaptureSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                        try {

                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);

                            setAutoFlash(mPreviewRequestBuilder);
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, Long.valueOf(exposureTime));
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, Integer.valueOf(sensitivity));
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION, Long.valueOf(frameDuration));

                            mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
                            mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest,
                                    mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);


                        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

To filter the image stream, I can use something like this:

```
public class MyCoolScanner extends AppCompatActivity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2 {
...
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    OpenCVNative.myCoolLibrary(mRgba.getNativeObjAddr(),mGray.getNativeObjAddr());
    return mGray;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will be off the next few days, but will keep checking responses to this question.

Answer (score 4):

Please find implementation of open CV with Android  , it may help you .

[Camera calibration With OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/camera-calibration/src/org/opencv/samples/cameracalibration)

Camera calibration - opencv 2.3.1 android

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-opencv/xXtUvdA1E4M

https://fossies.org/dox/opencv-3.2.0/CameraCalibrationActivity_8java_source.html

Comment: I looked at the code samples from the links you provided, but there's actually no "calibration" taking place for the camera, just someone applying a border to the frame, which doesn't help me at all.

What I need is to increase and decrease the sensitivity of the camera while still using OpenCV. I need that CPP capacity provided by OpenCV, but the camera calibration capacity provided by android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest.

Comment: Hi! did you solve this issue?  have same problem with camera2 module

Answer (score 0):

I believe OpenCV does not natively support use with android.camera2

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, OpenCV will not work with android.camera2, not without some kind of convoluted work around.

Comment: Here is a detailed tutorial: http://people.oregonstate.edu/~robinsti/CS_496/Tutorial/

Comment: Go Beavers! But actually, I couldn't get to that tutorial as it's locked behind some security. Got a 403 error permissions error.

Comment: Archive.org to resque: https://web.archive.org/web/20160429162315/http://people.oregonstate.edu/~robinsti/CS_496/Tutorial. The code is actually [on GitHub](https://github.com/friendoflore/OpenCv-for-Android-Color-Detection)